# How to compare differently nested dictionaries and lists in Python and find intersection?

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

I now have two (more or less complex) lists / dictionaries. The first one contains image names and the image pixel colors in hex. So it looks like this:

```
{
0: {'hex': ['#c3d6db', '#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'], 'filename': 'imag0'}, 
1: {'hex': ['#705b3c', '#6a5639', '#442f1e', '#4a3d28'], 'filename': 'img-xyz'},
…
}
```

So in this case I would have 2 images 2 x 2 px.
The second dictionary contains a lot of hex-values as keys and an id as value. It looks like:

```
{'#b0a7aa': '9976', '#595f5b': '19367', '#9a8f6a': '24095'…}
```

Now what I would like to do is to look if there is a color-value from my images (first list) that matches with one of the second list. If so, then I would like to know the filename from the first list and the value, the id,  of the matched key in the second list.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to produce an intersection between your `hex` lists and the hex-id dictionary:

```
for entry in images.values():
    for key in hexidmap.keys() & entry['hex']:
        print('{} {} {}'.format(entry['filename'], key, hexidmap[key]))
```

`&` produces the intersection between the key set and your list of hex values.

The above assumes you are using Python 3; if you are using Python 2 instead, use [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) instead of `.keys()`.

Demo:

```
>>> images = {
... 0: {'hex': ['#c3d6db', '#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'], 'filename': 'imag0'},
... 1: {'hex': ['#705b3c', '#6a5639', '#442f1e', '#4a3d28'], 'filename': 'img-xyz'},
... }
>>> hexidmap = {'#b0a7aa': '9976', '#595f5b': '19367', '#9a8f6a': '24095'}
>>> for entry in images.values():
...     for key in hexidmap.keys() & entry['hex']:
...         print('{} {} {}'.format(entry['filename'], key, hexidmap[key]))
...
imag0 #9a8f6a 24095
```

Comment: You are particular about using dict views.  Is this because view return a set of keys/values?

Comment: @pylang exactly; a view can be used as a set. There is no need to convert anything to sets here.

Comment: Elegant approach.

Comment: Sounds very good… but at the moment I have to following error: 

`for key in hexidmap.keys() & entry['hex']:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'`

what could be wrong?

Comment: @iMax you are using Python 2, so use `viewkeys` instead. `for key in hexidmap.viewkeys() & entry['hex']:`

Comment: @MartijnPieters wow! super cool! Thank you so much. Yes, I use Python 2. With `viewkeys()` instead it works very well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters one more question :) – my "setup" has changed. The hex-value is not anymore the key but instead the id is now the key. So it flipped.
But i can not use `for key in hexidmap.values() & entry['hex']:`
 Then i get the same error as bevore. Is there a simple trick how to make it work again?

Comment: @iMax: that change just made it impossible to do this efficiently. You can match the hex values with `hexidmap.viewvalues() & entry['hex']`, but you can't go back to the key in that case as you'd have to scan *all* keys for a match. At that point your only option is to iterate through all key-value pairs and test for matches. I'd keep the old map, if only to be able to do the work for this task.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay. Thanks for your capable answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in d1:
    print [(d1[index]["filename"], d2[i], i) for i in d1[index]["hex"] if i in d2]


>>> [('imag0', '24095', '#9a8f6a')]
[]
```

Comment: This doesn't print the hex values (just add `i`), and there is no need to print the key from `d1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dicta = {
        0: {'hex': ['#c3d6db', '#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'], 'filename': 'imag0'}, 
        1: {'hex': ['#705b3c', '#6a5639', '#442f1e', '#4a3d28'], 'filename': 'img-xyz'},
        }
dictb = {'#c3d6db': '9976', '#595f5b': '19367', '#9a8f6a': '24095'}
intersection = {}
for o in dicta.values():
  intersect = list(set(o['hex']) & set(dictb.keys()))
  intersection[o['filename']] = intersect if intersect else "No intersection"
print (intersection)
>>>{'imag0': ['#c3d6db', '#9a8f6a'], 'img-xyz': 'No intersection'}
```

Comment: You are not printing the requested info; the file name is missing.